# Add individual columns of a tuple value in Spark RDD using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

RDD looks as below:

```
[(u'1400-1459', (u'3.00', u'19.00')), (u'1200-1259', (u'3.00', u'9.00')), (u'1200-1259', (u'3.00', u'12.00')), (u'1100-1159', (u'3.00', u'14.00')), (u'1400-1459', (u'3.00', u'9.00'))]
```

I want to add individual columns from value for each key so that the output looks like :

```
[(u'1400-1459', (u'6.00', u'28.00')), (u'1200-1259', (u'6.00', u'21.00')), (u'1100-1159', (u'3.00', u'14.00'))]
```

Trying below command, but it's hanging forever

```
output =  joinedData.reduceByKey(lamdba x,y : (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: your values are all strings. you need to convert them to `float` before adding. Otherwise you're just concatenating them into a large string.

Comment: `output =  joinedData.map(lambda row: (row[0], (float(row[1][0]), float(row[1][1])))).reduceByKey(lamdba x,y : (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did as below:
final = joinedData.map(lambda row: (row[0], (float(row[1][0]), float(row[1][1]))))
output = final.reduceByKey(lambda x,y : (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
Getting error as :
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: got rid of the error by removing blank values. although , never seen the output as it hangs forever on output.take(5)